# Which title for a prologue: "Message from Manager" or "A Message from the Manager"?

Tags: phrase-usage

Well, there is a corporate brochure that starts with a page dedicated to managerial message as an introduction. The source Persian title is "پیام مدیریت" with literally means "message of management". Now I am stuck between one of the following options as translation for this:

> 1. **Message from Manager**  OR
> 2. **A Message from the Manager**

Just a reminder, the manager is **not** known, so I guess the second sentence has issues, by the way the first one does seem to me too pruned. Any ideas?

Comment: It doesn't really matter whether the manager is known to people or not - he or she is still **the** manager, if there is only one in question.  You do sometimes see sentences like the first [in headlines](http://grammar.about.com/od/fh/g/headlineseterm.htm), but headlines are really a very special case; in general you need to use articles.

Comment: What about: The manager's note?

Answer (score 1):

In English, the first version, I'm afraid, would appear as poorly translated from another language. "A Message from Management" is the most accurate and natural rendition of the Persian here.